# CentOS Postgres, Backup/Restore

Tags: centos, postgresql, database-backup

We recently inherited a company and their CentOS server with a Postgres running their CSR db. They have a backup system in place which we know nothing about.

It creates backups of the Postgres DB in i's entirity and creates two files, a .backup and .globals. What application are they using to create these backups?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL uses `pg_dump` to create database backups. The [pg_dump documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-pgdump.html) will tell you the various options that can be used.

[`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-pgrestore.html) is used to restore these dumps to a database.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pg_dump, there is also [pg_dumpall](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-pg-dumpall.html)-- they could be using either one. I would hazard a guess that the .globals file was created using `pg_dumpall --globals-only`. If these backups are being automatically generated then there  should be an entry in either the postgres users crontab ( run `crontab -l` as the postgres user) or in the /etc/crontab file that will tell you how the files are being created.